# Restrict slider dot to specific number in slick slide

Tags: angular, typescript, slick.js

I am using slick slide into angular application for showing image slide.
Scenario: If user upload more than 5 images then still into slide dots it should show only 5 dots.
[image]

Comment: Which lib are you using exactly ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I am using this lib ngx-slick-carousel